# In Javascript, how to combine numbers generated from 1 variable into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am generating the variable **num** through this code:

```
    var current = new Date();
    var a = this.proj.filter(some=>some.thing == 275).map(ab=>ab.data).join("").replace(/\\/g, '');
    var other = new Date(a);
```

var num:

```
var num = this.getTheDifferenceOfTwoDates(current, other);
```

This one variable calls a function which, as named, calculates the number of days between the current date and another date.

This generates a lot numbers which when var num is console logged, shows:

**Please note that console log is just to show you what it looks like**

[image]

They aren't part of an array, however I want to connect them so that they would form an array of numbers. How can I do this?

I've tried what is stated in the first comment below however creating an array, pushing etc. does not work.

```
    var arrayVar = [];
    arrayVar.push(num);
    console.log(arrayVar);
```

Returns:

[image]

Tried solution creating array outside function results in:

[image]

Comment: 1) create array, 2) instead of logging to console, push to array, 3) return/use array

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately it doesn't work:         var arrayVar = [];
        var abc = arrayVar.push(e);
        console.log(abc);

Comment: Please show the complete code that causes this output in the console

Comment: no, the return value of `push` is how many entries the array now has. You should look at the array that you just pushed into... `var arrayVar = []; arrayVar.push(abc); console.log(arrayVar);`

Comment: Thank you for the details. Is the above syntax correct?

Comment: you need to show your full function, I believe you are initializing your array locally, thats why the issue

Comment: You need to create the array _outside_ of the looping part.

Comment: So the numbers are only generated after it goes through the function. Before that they are two individual dates assigned to two different variables. Two variables which don't have an equal # of elements (var current only generates 1 element whereas other generates 1000+). Current is compared to each element in other and the difference between them is calculated. Doing that results in each element being put into an array with only that one element inside it (see added screenshot in qs).

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange the data you have into some kind of structure. Let's say you've got an array of "tuples", like this:

```
const inputData = [
  [current1, other1],
  [current2, other2],
];
```

Then you can process them all with a `map` operation:

```
var outputData = inputData.map(([current, other]) =>
  this.getTheDifferenceOfTwoDates(current, other));
```

Comment: I have over 1000 current and other dates so it won't quite work out. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are calling the function getTheDifferenceOfTwoDates in another custom function. So what you can do is, declare an empty array globally and push every time into that array whenever your getTheDifferenceOfTwoDates function executes.

Please refer to the code below.

```
// Declare array globally. 
var data=[];

// Function which is actually calculating difference.
function calculateDifferenc(){
    var current = new Date();
    var a = this.proj.filter(a=>a.thing == 275).map(ab=>ab.data).join("").replace(/\\/g, '');
    var other = new Date(c);
    var num = this.getTheDifferenceOfTwoDates(current, other);

    // Pushing the result into that global array.
    data.push(num);

    // To check the result.
    Console.log("Data = ", data);
}
```